# Android AsyncTask launched from Service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I want to implement a service which will launch an AsyncTask.

In the AsyncTask onProgressUpdate() I want to update a TableLayout in the main thread.

All is fine, but for one doubt: **How do I handle the situation where the main thread has been destroyed or is not visible?** 
The service will continue until it stopSelf() and this is what I want.
But how does the AsyncTask know not to update the TableLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is along the lines of lettting the service know when the main Activity is visible or not through messages on onResume() and onPause().

The service in turn will set a flag in the AsyncTak, when the flag is false the onProgressUpdate() will exit without doing the UI update.

So I guess, if I understood the Services documentation right, my Service will have to be started-sticky and also bound by the same activity. I only need to figure out how to re-bind the running service.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as I read your second post I understand things better.

You have a classic producer-consumer problem here. The AsyncTask of the service is producing something that a consumer (the main activity) needs to display. The solution is to use a LinkedBlockingQueue to store all downloaded items. The activity will need to have its own AsyncTask that will poll from the LinkedBlockingQueue. Here is the basic approach:

The service has an AsyncTask that downloads data. Each item is stored in an unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue.

The activity starts an AsyncTask from onResume and cancels it from onPause. This task will poll the LinkedBlockingQueue and then display each item in the TableLayout.

Comment: I think you read the post too fast, If the UI activity is visible I need to update a TableLayout. The notification area is not the solution. Think of a background task that has to download 100 files and displays live which files were already loaded in a TableLayout or ListView.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: You have given me a second solution to what I have right now. I have an AsyncTask which produces into a ArrayList and displays its progress to UI. I want to rewrite my code to use services because I need the producer to stay alive even if the user goes to other application. From what I read in your answer this is not the case in your solution. See my own answer.

Comment: No, my solution will work perfectly, even if the activity is destroyed. The activity is the observer and completely decoupled from the producer. The LinkedBlockingQueue has to be maintained by the Application class or the service so that it stays alive even when the activity may be destroyed.

Comment: @ilomambo read my suggestion carefully. There are two async tasks. One started by the service which is the producer and is always working. The activity also has an async task which does the polling. It is a good idea, but not necessary, for the activity to cancel its async task when backgrounded to save battery life. That is just an optimization. The key is to have two separate async tasks.